# How to load resource file in jenkins plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to load a resource file which is in src/main/resources folder as part of Jenkins plugin. It is always giving me **FileNotFoundException**. Can someone please explain how to make it work?

**Exception message:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/Report/WEB -INF/lib/Report.jar!/properties.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: How are you accessing the resource? I assume you are accessing it via File(...) ? If so this simply wrong..You have to use `getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...")` instead...

Comment: I am doing it using getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...") but still it gives me the exception

Answer (score 0):

The question is asked long back but I just thought to share my answer in case it helps someone out there who faced this issue similar to me.

Follow these steps: It works in my case:

1. Place your file in the "resources" folder thats typically on the
   path "src/main/resources". In IntelliJ IDE, mark the resources
   directory as "resource root".
2. As the file(s) are placed inside resources, they are in a directory
   thats on the build path so maven should be able to load this without
   setting additional build path.
3. Let say the file name is "application-env.properties". Following code block should 
   pull the file from resource folder at jenkins plugin run time.

   ```
       InputStream inputStream = null;
       try{
         String resourceName = "application-env.properties";
         Properties props = new Properties();
         ClassLoader cl = <NameOfThisClass>.class.getClassLoader();
         try (InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
           props.load(stream);
         }
         //read props or return the same to the caller
       } 
       finally {
         if (inputStream != null) {
           inputStream.close();
         }
       }
   ```